# Why my navbar doesn't show up?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I'm trying to set my window's root view controller to a UITabBarController with a UINavigationController but for some reason the navigation bar doesn't show up. Anybody knows why?
Thanks

Here is my method:

```
- (void) showUserOnlyScreen
{
    UITabBarController *tabbarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    SSHomeViewController *homeVC = [[SSHomeViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController *homeNav = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:homeVC];

    [tabbarController setViewControllers:@[homeNav]];


   self.window.rootViewController = tabbarController;
   [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

}
```

Comment: Did you mean SSHomeViewController showed but navigation bar not?

Comment: @Lumialxk that's right I got the Home VC and the tab bar showing up but not the nav bar

Answer (score 0):

Your code is OK.

Check if the UINavigationBar is transparent by applying a border on it:

```
homeNav.navigationBar.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
homeNav.navigationBar.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
```

Check also if you mistakenly hide the navigationbar on your SSHomeViewController controller with this:

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:NO];
```